# How to show pages in menu without link

Tags: menus, pages, links

I need to have a menu like this:

```
- a (link to a)
-- b (link to b, children of a)
-- c (link to c, children of a)
- d (NO LINK, #)
-- e (link to e)
```

I have the menu composed by the pages, as wordpress default. I want that "d" links to nothing (#), because i have a blank page and it doesn't have sense to exist.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a custom link (wp-dashboard > Appearance > Menus) using a dummy url, then add the custom link to your menu, and edit the menu item and remove the url.